# GeoServer crashing when seeding via GeoWebCache

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I am using GeoWebCache to cache my tiles (~ 250 000), but after a while my GeoServer (version 2.18.0. my I've checked the log files but I did not see any error message from GWC, the last messages is about a successful WMS requests and the restarting logs.

Edit:

I use Docker containers to run geoserver and postgis, so after geoserver craches, docker automatically restart the geoserver.

These are the last log messages:

```
2021-01-17 18:50:52,985 INFO [geoserver.flow] - releasing flow controllers for [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap]
2021-01-17 18:50:52,986 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request completed, running requests: 0, blocked requests: 0
2021-01-17 18:50:54,002 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-01-17 18:50:54,017 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] starting, processing through flow controllers
2021-01-17 18:50:54,019 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request control-flow performed, running requests: 1, blocked requests: 0
2021-01-17 18:50:55,071 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[21.533203125 : 21.5771484375, 48.6474609375 : 48.69140625]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/png
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 1024
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@d6547340, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@b193de5c, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@8a863bf4, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9c98a986]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/png, STYLES=, WIDTH=1024, HEIGHT=1024, LAYERS=test_points, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=21.533203125,48.6474609375,21.5771484375,48.69140625, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:4326
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=test_large_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_medium_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_small_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_minor_scale]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 1024
2021-01-17 18:50:55,090 INFO [geoserver.flow] - releasing flow controllers for [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap]
2021-01-17 18:50:55,103 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request completed, running requests: 0, blocked requests: 0
2021-01-17 18:50:56,346 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-01-17 18:50:56,554 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] starting, processing through flow controllers
2021-01-17 18:50:56,558 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request control-flow performed, running requests: 1, blocked requests: 0
2021-01-17 18:50:59,309 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[21.5771484375 : 21.62109375, 48.6474609375 : 48.69140625]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/png
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 1024
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@d6547340, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@b193de5c, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@8a863bf4, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9c98a986]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/png, STYLES=, WIDTH=1024, HEIGHT=1024, LAYERS=test_points, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=21.5771484375,48.6474609375,21.62109375,48.69140625, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:4326
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=test_large_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_medium_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_small_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_minor_scale]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 1024
2021-01-17 18:50:59,395 INFO [geoserver.flow] - releasing flow controllers for [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap]
2021-01-17 18:50:59,407 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request completed, running requests: 0, blocked requests: 0
2021-01-17 18:51:01,906 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-01-17 18:51:02,228 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] starting, processing through flow controllers
2021-01-17 18:51:02,240 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request control-flow performed, running requests: 1, blocked requests: 0
2021-01-17 18:51:16,074 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[21.62109375 : 21.6650390625, 48.6474609375 : 48.69140625]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/png
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 1024
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@d6547340, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@b193de5c, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@8a863bf4, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9c98a986]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/png, STYLES=, WIDTH=1024, HEIGHT=1024, LAYERS=test_points, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=21.62109375,48.6474609375,21.6650390625,48.69140625, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:4326
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=test_large_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_medium_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_small_scale], StyleImpl[ name=test_minor_scale]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 1024
2021-01-17 18:51:16,107 INFO [geoserver.flow] - releasing flow controllers for [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap]
2021-01-17 18:51:16,108 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request completed, running requests: 0, blocked requests: 0
2021-01-17 18:52:29,513 WARN [geoserver.monitor] - monitoring storage memory not found, falling back to 'memory'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,346 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:31,608 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loading catalog...
2021-01-17 18:52:31,925 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'pophatch'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,928 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'population'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,929 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'rain'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,931 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'dem'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,932 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'capitals'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,934 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'generic'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,945 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'points_53000'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,946 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poly_landmarks'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,947 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poi'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,948 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_roads'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,949 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'line'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,951 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_streams'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,952 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'cite_lakes'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,953 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'giant_polygon'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,954 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'point'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,957 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'burg'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,962 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'test_large_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,963 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'grass'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,967 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'test_minor_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,968 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'polygon'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,968 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,972 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'green'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,973 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'tiger_roads'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,975 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'restricted'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,980 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'test_medium_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,993 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'test_small_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:31,998 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded default workspace cite
2021-01-17 18:52:32,229 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sf'
2021-01-17 18:52:32,252 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sde'
2021-01-17 18:52:32,260 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'nurc'
2021-01-17 18:52:32,263 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'tiger'
2021-01-17 18:52:32,267 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'topp'
2021-01-17 18:52:32,278 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'test_points'
2021-01-17 18:52:32,308 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'it.geosolutions'
2021-01-17 18:52:32,316 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'cite'
2021-01-17 18:52:33,345 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'sfdem', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:37,894 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'sfdem', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:37,993 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'sfdem'
2021-01-17 18:52:38,537 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'sf', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:38,587 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'streams', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:38,594 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'streams'
2021-01-17 18:52:38,611 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'bugsites', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:38,619 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'bugsites'
2021-01-17 18:52:38,637 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'roads', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:38,646 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'roads'
2021-01-17 18:52:38,663 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'restricted', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:38,670 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'restricted'
2021-01-17 18:52:38,688 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'archsites', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:38,701 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'archsites'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,222 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'test points', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,305 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'test_points_large_scale', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,311 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'test_points_large_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,319 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'test_points_medium_scale', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,333 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'test_points_medium_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,486 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'test_points_minor_scale', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,492 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'test_points_minor_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,506 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'test_points_small_scale', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,509 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'test_points_small_scale'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,533 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'arcGridSample', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,547 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Arc_Sample', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,559 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Arc_Sample'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,563 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'worldImageSample', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,573 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Img_Sample', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,590 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Img_Sample'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,603 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'img_sample2', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,639 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Pk50095', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,651 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Pk50095'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,655 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'mosaic', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,667 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'mosaic', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,672 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'mosaic'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,684 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'nyc', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,708 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'giant_polygon', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,712 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'giant_polygon'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,742 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poly_landmarks', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,759 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poly_landmarks'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,772 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tiger_roads', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,782 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tiger_roads'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,796 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poi', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,801 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poi'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,820 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'states_shapefile', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,836 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'states', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,840 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'states'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,847 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'taz_shapes', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,868 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_roads', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,871 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_roads'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,879 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_cities', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,880 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_cities'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,886 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_water_bodies', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,889 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_water_bodies'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,894 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_state_boundaries', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:39,895 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_state_boundaries'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,941 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tasmania'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,949 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'test_points'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,967 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'spearfish'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,982 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tiger-ny'
2021-01-17 18:52:39,999 INFO [org.geoserver] - Read catalog in 8.382 s
2021-01-17 18:52:40,357 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'csw', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:40,382 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wcs', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:40,450 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WPSInfoImpl-61e52f57:176f600560d:-8000', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:40,501 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wms', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:40,556 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wfs', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:40,573 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl-5662192b:17711b12ef3:-8000', enabled
2021-01-17 18:52:40,976 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache.xml' in directory '/opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc'.
2021-01-17 18:52:41,412 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:41,412 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:41,412 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:41,959 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - TileLayerConfiguration file validated fine.
2021-01-17 18:52:42,479 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:42,523 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Read GridSet InspireCRS84Quad
2021-01-17 18:52:42,526 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:42,730 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog
2021-01-17 18:52:42,731 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers
2021-01-17 18:52:42,731 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers
2021-01-17 18:52:42,969 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loaded 27 tile layers in 236.6 ms
2021-01-17 18:52:43,002 INFO [storage.BlobStoreAggregator] - BlobStoreConfiguration /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc contained no blob store infos.
2021-01-17 18:52:43,027 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ***********************************************************************************************************************************
2021-01-17 18:52:43,028 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found System environment variable GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR set to /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc, using it as the default prefix. ***
2021-01-17 18:52:43,030 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ***********************************************************************************************************************************
2021-01-17 18:52:43,626 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
2021-01-17 18:52:49,837 INFO [flow.config] - Loaded control-flow rule: ows.global=100
2021-01-17 18:52:49,840 INFO [flow.config] - Loaded control-flow rule: ows.wms.getmap=10
2021-01-17 18:52:49,841 INFO [flow.config] - Loaded control-flow rule: ows.wfs.getfeature.application/msexcel=4
2021-01-17 18:52:49,850 INFO [flow.config] - Loaded control-flow rule: user=6
2021-01-17 18:52:49,850 INFO [flow.config] - Loaded control-flow rule: ows.gwc=16
2021-01-17 18:52:49,859 INFO [flow.config] - Loaded control-flow rule: user.ows.wps.execute=1000/d;30s
2021-01-17 18:52:49,862 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Control-flow active with 6 flow controllers
2021-01-17 18:52:50,345 WARN [turbojpeg.TurboJPEGMapResponse] - The turbo jpeg encoder is available for usage
2021-01-17 18:52:50,968 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 5 bindable processes in GeoServer specific processes
2021-01-17 18:52:51,079 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 89 bindable processes in Deprecated processes
2021-01-17 18:52:51,142 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 48 bindable processes in Geometry processes
2021-01-17 18:52:51,143 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 1 bindable processes in PolygonLabelProcess
2021-01-17 18:52:51,150 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:ConvolveCoverage as the input kernel of type class javax.media.jai.KernelJAI cannot be handled
2021-01-17 18:52:51,161 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input zones of type class java.lang.Object cannot be handled
2021-01-17 18:52:51,162 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input nodata of type class it.geosolutions.jaiext.range.Range cannot be handled
2021-01-17 18:52:51,162 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input rangeData of type class java.lang.Object cannot be handled
2021-01-17 18:52:51,164 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the output zonal statistics of type interface java.util.List cannot be handled
2021-01-17 18:52:51,174 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 18 bindable processes in Raster processes
2021-01-17 18:52:51,192 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 31 bindable processes in Vector processes
2021-01-17 18:52:52,035 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory '/opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc'.
2021-01-17 18:52:52,150 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory '/opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc'.
2021-01-17 18:52:52,162 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:52,163 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - Quota config is: /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2021-01-17 18:52:52,163 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:58,393 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:58,394 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - Quota config is: /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2021-01-17 18:52:58,394 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
2021-01-17 18:52:58,439 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
2021-01-17 18:52:58,440 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas. 
2021-01-17 18:52:58,441 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 27 layers attached to global quota 1.95 GB
2021-01-17 18:52:58,485 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS
2021-01-17 18:53:04,222 INFO [geoserver.monitor] - Monitor extension enabled
2021-01-17 18:53:05,146 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
2021-01-17 18:53:05,195 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...
2021-01-17 18:53:05,221 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.
2021-01-17 18:53:05,407 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
2021-01-17 18:53:05,408 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
2021-01-17 18:53:07,002 INFO [geoserver.config] - Initiated CatalogTimeStampUpdater
2021-01-17 18:53:08,036 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to set ordering between tiff readers spi
2021-01-17 18:53:12,662 WARN [servlet.BaseMapServlet] - Cannot delete file:/usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore
2021-01-17 18:53:14,205 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
2021-01-17 18:53:14,216 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
2021-01-17 18:53:14,727 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level
2021-01-17 18:53:14,731 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
2021-01-17 19:04:32,125 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 172.21.0.1
2021-01-17 19:04:32,194 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 2188ms
2021-01-17 19:04:34,649 INFO [geoserver.security] - Strong cryptography is available
2021-01-17 19:04:36,784 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 172.21.0.1
2021-01-17 19:04:36,785 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 4193ms
```

Comment: try turning up the logging level to GEOSERVER_DEBUG - also we need to know how you are seeding, how much memory is available for GS and GWC, please use the [edit] button to add this information to your question